# Optimally identifying locale of String ResourceDictionary?

Tags: wpf, localization

I have a resource dictionary of localized strings. I want to set a property on it (e.g., its `Tag`) to the name of the locale so that I can easily identify the `ResourceDictionary` from code-behind. (Otherwise, I do some dirty filename parsing, which offends me in various ways.)

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    Tag="de-DE">

    <system:String x:Key="Hello">Hallo Welt!</system:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

But this results in a `XamlParseException` since `ResourceDictionary.Tag` does not exist. Is there another way to set the tag here? Or is there a better way to achieve my goal? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
To clarify, I have a directory of several `ResourceDictionary` XAML files, each containing localized strings for a particular locale. When the user sets the locale to German, for example, my application looks in the aforementioned directory for the XAML file that ends with `"de-DE.xaml"` and loads that file's resource dictionary. I prefer not to be bound by the filename in this manner. I suppose a disadvantage to using something like a `Tag` would be that I'd have to load the dictionary before I can determine its actual locale, so the filename parsing wins on that front. The ideal (to me) solution does not rely on the filename nor requires loading the resource dictionary.

Comment: Woh. No. Why do you need to know the Tag in the Code-Behind?

Comment: The dictionaries are loaded from a custom resource-dictionary manager in code-behind. I need a simple way to select/lookup a resource dictionary by locale, but I don't know how to implement this association.

Comment: Right. but are these ResourceDictionaries Resources or Content?

Comment: By the way, WPF already implements a localization method. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621.aspx

Comment: @NestorArturo, true, I'm aware, but my application cannot use LocBaml. The resource dictionaries are loose XAML files that can be modified at runtime in a text editor.

Comment: Why are they content? Are your clients modifying these files?

Comment: @user46874 - Yea I figured. Well your pretty SOL. You can do it filename and a lot of error checking of the long approach I mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few approaches

- If your resource dictionary is a REAL resources then just have the filename as the culture. I do not see the problem here because only the developers will have access to the file name.
- Have a dummy key (Horrible Approach)

  ```
  <system:String x:Key="Culture">de-DE</system:String>
  ```

  This is bad because you have to physically open each dictionary and make sure the first string is a real culture.
- If your resource dictionary is a content file then do the same as if it was a resource just make sure you teat errors if you end users delete files.